# Is there a way to shorten a long array name without assigning it to a new array?

Tags: javascript, arrays, json

A json response has an array of objects that I want to iterate without having to use the full (I don't know what you would call "results.data.messages.items") long name:

```
for (var i = 0; i < results.data.messages.items.length; i++) {
    console.log( results.data.messages.items[i].id );
}
```

I know how to iterate over items, but I can't find any way to shorten that down so I don't have to type `results.data.messages.items[i].property_name` each time and instead could just do `item[i].property_name`.

I don't want to duplicate the array just for the purpose of having a shorter name.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assigning the array to a new variable does *not* duplicate the array—it still refers to the same object. The new variable works sort of like an "alias". Therefore, this is absolutely fine:

```
var element = results.data.messages.items[i];
```

Alternatively, you could declare a new variable outside the loop:

```
var items = results.data.messages.items;
```

Comment: This is exactly what I was hoping for. I figured if I did that it would duplicate the array so I'll take your word for it that it isn't. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you shorten it to the element at the specific index, instead of the array:

```
for (var i = 0; i < results.data.messages.items.length; i++) {
    var item = results.data.messages.items[i];
    console.log(item.id);
}
```

**EDIT**

To keep it simpler, you could iterate through it using the array protoype method `forEach`, that already assigns each element with any name as you wish:

```
results.data.messages.items.forEach(function(item) {
    console.log(item.id);
});
```

Comment: Thanks. The item = is the line is what I was hoping would work, I didn't know if it'd duplicate the array or not. As for the forEach, I looked into that before and read that it's quite a bit slower than the way I'm currently doing although it wouldn't really slow me down for my purposes.

Answer (score 1):

You could always define these in the for loop's definition

```
for (var i = 0, items = results.data.messages.items; i < items.length; i++) {
 console.log( items[i].id );
}
```

There is also the usually avoided [with](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/with)

```
with( results.data.messages ){
 for (var i = 0; i < items.length; i++){
  console.log( items[i].id );
 }
}
```

Comment: I didn't know you could define it in the definition, that's pretty helpful. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Assign it to a separate variable *before* your loop:

```
var items = results.data.messages.items;
for (var i = 0; i < items.length; i++) {
    console.log( items[i].id );
}
```

This does not create a new array. Just a new variable that references the same array.

Another option would be to use array's builtin methods to reduce duplication:

```
results.data.messages.items.forEach(function (item) {
    console.log(item.id);
});
```